# Separating elements in an Array JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array that is generated based on user clicks from various questions and alerts like this:

> Team A, Player 1, Yellow, C1

This kind of array is created every time an event happens (in a football match). After the match is complete I want to take each of these events and put them into my database. I would like to know how I can separate each part of the array with a `;` so that the array that will be exploded will look something like this:

> Team A, Player 1, Yellow, C1; Team B, Player 5, Red, S6

I have no problem creating the first array and just need to know how to add in the `;` I am wondering if this perhaps becomes an array within an array?

Thank-you in advance

Comment: I don't understand what your data looks like. Is this an array of strings like `["Team A", "Player 1", "Yellow", "C1", ... ]` and so on, or is it a string like `"Team A, Player 1, Yellow, C1, ..."`?

Comment: ok, so to clarify a bit further. This is for an app that will be used in football(soccer) matches by a referee. when they want to give a yellow card they will select the team, then a player from a `<select>` and then the card, so yellow in this case and then the reason which is what C1, C2 stand for.
I am pushing each element as mentioned above into an array which is producing the before mentioned output and would like to separate each of these entries with a `;` so that when i come to explode them it will be much easier for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe the following solves your problem (as long as I understand it correctly):

```
var array = ["Team A", "Player 1", "Yellow", "C1", 
             "Team B", "Player 5", "Red", "S6"];

var result = "";
for ( var i = 0; i < array.length; i += 4) {
    result += array.slice(i, i+4).join(",");
    if ( i+4 < array.length ) result += ";";
}

console.log(result);
// prints: Team A,Player 1,Yellow,C1;Team B,Player 5,Red,S6;
```

Later you can reverse this operation using `split`:

```
var array2 = result.split(/,|;/);
// array == array2
```

Comment: I have tried some of the code you have put above. It does now add the `;` in after the array is populated but as any number of events could happen in a match it will always keep adding to it. When I go through and add another event it appears that result no longer remembers the old event. so instead of having >Team A, Player 1, Yellow, C1; Team B, Player 5, Red, S6
it just shows >Team B, Player 5, Red, S6

Comment: @Robbob - I've change `splice` to `slice`. It should be better now.

Comment: thank-you so much. it is nearly there based on what you have put above but the `;` is occuring in the wrong place so at the moment I am getting `,Team A, Player 1, Yellow; C1, Team B, Player 6, Red; C2 `etc...I am thinking that the values of the i's may need to be changed slightly?

Comment: @Robbob - it looks like your array is in different format than mine. Are you sure it's first element is "Team A", not an empty string ""? What prints console.log(array)?

Comment: I think your right. it prints out `, Team A, Player 1, Yellow; C1` Clearly the problem is that `,` at the start of the array

Comment: Just sorted it. From when I was trying stuff earlier I had declared the array as `[[]]` rather than just `[]` so all working fine now. Thank-you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I understand your issue:

I think a 2 dimensional array would be the easiest way to achieve what you are after.  You could also look at creating objects and placing those objects into an array.  It appears as though you are doing this but I am not entirely sure as your example is not very informative.

Answer (score 0):

You should ideally push these strings into an array and then push them to an array that includes all the other arrays (2 dimensional array) :

Example: http://jsbin.com/ecoput/2/edit

```
var data = [["Team A","Player 1","Yellow","C1"],["Team B","Player 5","Red","S6"]]
```

After this, you should `join` the array.

```
data.join(";");
```

This will result in:

```
"Team A,Player 1,Yellow,C1;Team B,Player 5,Red,S6"
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful to see your code to know how the array is being created, but your last statement is probably on the right track. It sounds like you need either an associative array, or better yet, a collection of some sort. What does this data represent?

Player 1 from Team A received a Yellow card? What is C1? If you can post some code and explain what it is that you're trying to capture it would be more helpful.

Answer (score 0):

From your question I guess that you are using strings, not actual arrays.

Consider using array of objects, because event is a single entity, not a list of entities:

```
[{team:"Team A", player:"Player 1", type:"Yellow", code:"C1"}, 
 {team:"Team B", player:"Player 5", type:"Red", code:"S6"}]
```

Code to add an event to array of objects:

```
function addEvent(events, team, player, type, code) {
  events.push({team:team, player:player, type:type, code:code});
}
```

If you are required to store individual events as arrays:

```
[["Team A", "Player 1", "Yellow", "C1"], 
 ["Team B", "Player 5","Red", "S6"]]
```

You can use this code to add an event to 'array of arrays':

```
function addEvent(events, team, player, type, code) {
  events.push([team, player, type, code]);
}
```